# Why do I get a TypeError "must be a pair of numbers" when trying to use custom Point tuple with pygame?

Tags: python, data-structures, tuples, point

I am trying to make a Point tuple that would work like this:

```
p1 = (3, 5)
p1.x
# returns 3
p1.y
# returns 5
p1
# returns (3, 5)
p1.x = 7
# mutable
```

So instead of `p1[0]` i can just call `p1.x` and at the same time calling `p1` returns the tuple, not an object.

I want to use this data structure with Pygame. I tried to use the `recordclass` library like this:

```
Point = recordclass('Point', 'x y')
some_tuple = (0, 0)
start_point = Point(some_tuple)

pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), start_point, 5)
```

And the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Repos\PyCharm\Sailboat\main.py", line 85, in <module>
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), start_point, 5)
TypeError: center argument must be a pair of numbers
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 As per last line in the OP's example, a named tuple won't work as they need it to be mutable.

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, I mean the recordclass library.

Comment: "and at the same time calling p1 returns the tuple, not an object" - tuples are objects. What made you decide you wanted something other than an object? If we know the motivation, we can help you figure out what you actually need.

Comment: @user2357112 oh maybe I stated that wrong, it returns a tuple object that I can easily feed to some functions in libraries I did not write

Comment: Then just make your point class iterable; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74393947/make-python-dataclass-iterable

Comment: @MatBailie could you explain how that would work?

Comment: One hacky example; https://trinket.io/python3/01f96b0a65 (Please update your question with the libraries you need this to work for.)

Comment: Thanks to all and especially to @MatBailie, you helped the most :)

Comment: `Point(x[0], x[1])` may be replaceable with `Point(*x)`

Comment: Right, it works with unpacking like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution:

```
Point = recordclass('Point', 'x y')
some_tuple = (0, 0)
start_point = Point(some_tuple)

#...
# changing to another Point using a tuple
start_point = Point(*some_tuple)

#...
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 0), start_point, 5)
# works fine
```

As it turned out the line `start_point = Point(some_tuple)` was the real issue, the library doesn't assign it properly nor does it tell that it shouldn't be done like that. Changing it to `start_point = Point(some_tuple[0], some_tuple[1])` or `start_point = Point(*some_tuple)` fixed the issue.

Comment: This shows why [mre] is important. Your question didn't have the line of code you fixed. You should always ensure your question replicates your problem entirely, and test that before you post it.

Comment: Also, to make it clear to future readers that you have solved the problem, you could mark your answer as accepted (using the green check mark on the left).

Comment: @mkrieger1 I need to wait 2 days for some reason, that's why it isn't marked yet.

Comment: All classes that are built using factory functions (recordclass, make_data class) and by inheritance from dataobject are initialized by default by listing all arguments: cls(x, y, z) or cls(x, y, z=2) or cls(x=1, y=2, z=3) either cls(*args) or cls(**kwargs).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```py
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> p = SimpleNamespace(x=3, y=5)
>>> p.x
3
>>> p.y
5
>>> p.x = 7
>>> p
namespace(x=7, y=5)
```

Comment: That won't allow the object to be used as a normal tuple. For example, try `len(p)` or `p[0]`

Comment: @MatBailie I'm not aware of any way to do that without declaring your own class. I think the simplest way is to subclass `typing.NamedTuple`

Answer (score -1):

Just create a custom class named `Tuple` like this:

```py
class Tuple:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  def __str__(self):
    return f"({self.x}, {self.y})"
  def __len__(self):
    return len((self.x, self.y))
  def __getitem__(self, i):
    return (self.x, self.y)[i]
  
p1 = Tuple(3, 5)
print('p1.x\t',p1.x)
print('p1.y\t',p1.y)
print('p1\t',p1)
p1.x = 7
print('p1\t',p1)
print('p1[0]\t',p1[0])
print('len(p1)\t',len(p1))
```

The output will be:

```
p1.x     3
p1.y     5
p1   (3, 5)
p1   (7, 5)
p1[0]    7
len(p1)  2
```

Comment: That won't allow the object to be used as a normal tuple. For example, try `len(p1)` or `p1[0]`

Comment: Now, it can use as a normal tuple

Comment: In part yes, but only in part. Try iterating over it; `for i in p1:`. What I'm getting at is that the op expressed a desire to use it in place of a tuple, so you should implement a tuple's interface as a whole, not just a random subset.